# Conditional column in DataFrame: where's the mistake?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's start with a Pandas DataFrame `df` with numerical columns `pS`, `pS0` and `pE`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0.1,0.2,0.7],[0.3,0.6,0.1],[0.9,0.1,0.0]], 
                  columns=['pS','pE','pS0'])
```

We want to build a column indicating which of the 3 previous is dominating. I achieved it this way:

```
def class_morph(x):
    y = [x['pE'],x['pS'],x['pS0']]
    y.sort(reverse=True)
    if (y[0] == y[1]):
        return 'U'
    elif (x['pE'] == y[0]):
        return 'E'
    elif (x['pS'] == y[0]):
        return 'S'
    elif (x['pS0'] == y[0]):
        return 'S0'

df['Morph'] = df.apply(class_morph, axis=1)
```

Which gives the correct result:

[image]

But my initial try was the following:

```
def class_morph(x):
    if (x['pE'] > np.max(x['pS'],x['pS0'])):
        return 'E'
    elif (x['pS'] > np.max(x['pE'],x['pS0'])):
        return 'S'
    elif (x['pS0'] > np.max(x['pS'],x['pE'])):
        return 'S0'
    else:
        return 'U'
```

Which returned something wrong:

[image]

Could somebody explain to me what is my mistake in my first try?

Comment: Except for the tie, `U` case, you could use `df.idxmax(axis=1).str[1:]`.

Comment: `df.apply(class_morph, axis=1)` should have raised `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"` when using the second version of `class_morph`. If you fix that error by changing `np.max` to `max`, `df.apply(class_morph, axis=1)` returns the first (correct) result, not the second.

Comment: @John Galt Thanks!

Comment: @unutbu Strange, it didn't raise the error... Thank you very much!